# How do add a the Account Admin

Tags: azure

We do not have an account administrator for our Azure account.  The person who was the administrator left and his account is not longer valid.   We need to assign the administrator role to another person. How does that role get set up or assigned?

Comment: I’m shooting off the cuff here but if you can’t currently login as an admin, then you can’t create an admin. You’ll have to contact Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no one at all with admin rights then the only way you can resolve this is to contact Microsoft support and ask them to do this for you. You will need to prove you are the owners of the subscription.